# Adobe air native extensions / Google Checkout

Tags: air, google-checkout, air-native-extension

Is it possible to use Adobe AIR 3.0 Native extensions to interface with Google Checkout so in-app purchase can be made?

If so: has anyone tried this?
If not: why not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I have tried this.

Comment: Here is a good plugin for this: http://www.milkmangames.com/blog/tools/#androidiab

Answer (score 0):

From within a browser environment you can use Google In-App Payments to sell digital and virtual goods.

More info and documentation here:

http://code.google.com/apis/inapppayments/docs/index.html